# image responsive in loop

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

The problem i am facing is simple i have created a div with image and text and that image and text is in loop.
so for desktop it is right but for tablet i need the image should come side by side but instead it is coming below one another.
this is image in tablet i m getting[image: the image i am getting]

this image is what i need
[image: this is the image i need in tablet view]

```html
                <?php for ($i = 0; $i < 3; $i++) { ?>
                    
                    <div class="row padding-1">
                        <div class="col-lg-4  col-sm-3">
                            <img src="<?php echo URL ?>public/images/group.jpg" class="group-pic">
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-lg-8  col-sm-4">
      <span class="right-news" style="">VALIDATION DE QUATRE (4) GUIDES POUR LA CONDUITE DES MISSIONS DE L’IGF<span></div>

                    </div>
                <?php } ?>
```

I need some help here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try setting the column size for `sm` smaller screens(tablets) also the same as for `lg` larger screens(desktops)
And you have put the loop with the row class. Change your code as follows,

```
<div class="row padding-1">
<?php for ($i = 0; $i < 3; $i++) {?>

 <div class="col-lg-4 col-sm-4">
  <img src="<?php echo URL ?>public/images/group.jpg" class="group-pic">
 </div> 
 <div class="col-lg-8 col-sm-8">                         
 <span class="right-news" style="">VALIDATION DE QUATRE (4) GUIDES POUR LA CONDUITE DES MISSIONS DE L’IGF<span>
 </div> 

<?php } ?>
</div>
```

Comment: also i want to limit the loop to 2 for tablet?

Answer (score 1):

Your loop is outside a `.row` class. So a new `.row` is created each time. Instead wrap your loop around a boostrap `.col-*`. Where the `*` must be the size you want the col to be.

Example:

```
<div class="row">

    <?php for ($i = 0; $i < 3; $i++) { ?>

    <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-4 col-xs-6">
        <div class="row padding-1">
            <div class="col-lg-4  col-sm-3">
                <img src="<?php echo URL ?>public/images/group.jpg" class="group-pic">
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-8  col-sm-4">
                <span class="right-news" style="">VALIDATION DE QUATRE (4) GUIDES POUR LA CONDUITE DES MISSIONS DE L’IGF<span>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <?php } ?>

</div>
```